# How to replace the NSMutableArray section object in UITableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

Below is my `NSMutableArray` response

```
(
    (
    0,
    1,
    1,
    0,
    0,
    0
),
    (
    0,
    0,
    0
)
)
```

This is my code,here i need to replace the object

```
[CoutReplace[indexPath.section] replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"1"];
```

when i am using this code it is crashing.
Bellow is my crash report.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000e6fe40'
```

Here "CoutReplace" is NSMutableArray.

Comment: What is CoutReplace in your code? Can you post cellForRow and other related UITableView methods?

Comment: CountReplace is NSMutableArray

Comment: check indexPath.section and indexPath.row values. print them if they correct. Use hard coded values for now

Comment: [CoutReplace[0] replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@"1"]; i tried this hard coding but it s crashing.

Comment: Did you check if CoutReplace has anything or not?

Comment: Please explain further; "Not working" doesn't help. What happens? You say you get a crash when you hard code section and row - what is the detail of that crash?